# Print all values from column using custom predicate

Tags: t-sql

How can I print next values 
**'aa, bb, cc, dd, ee'**
from DB column, like that: 
**'aa-bb, aa-cc, aa-dd, aa-ee, etc'**?

NOTE: If I have, for example following value: 'aa-bb', so 'bb-aa' should be skipped out

My TSQL Example doesn't work:

```
select l.SURNAME + '-' + l1.SURNAME
from LECTURERS l cross join LECTURERS l1 
where l.CITY = 'Kyiv' and l.SURNAME <> l1.SURNAME and LEFT(l1.SURNAME, 
charindex('-', l1.SURNAME)) <> l.SURNAME
```

Prints me following **'aa-bb, aa-cc, aa-dd, aa-ee'**, but how can I except **'aa-bb' <> 'bb-aa'**

Comment: What happens if you change `l.SURNAME <> l1.SURNAME` to `l.SURNAME < l1.SURNAME`?

Comment: If you have a column that stores data like this, then you have a flaw in your database design and you should fix it. For more information, read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Comment: @ZoharPeled Based on the query I _think_ the question is about creating all possible pairs of `Lecturers` without duplicates, i.e. "Fred & Wilma" is equivalent to "Wilma & Fred" so only one of the pairs should be included in the results. It doesn't appear to be a case of horribly denormalized data. Some additional clarification from the OP would certainly help.

Comment: @HABO Perhaps I've misread the question. We will have to wait for clarification, as you wrote.